# jQuery datatables: I want to put a datatable on the left and a div on the right

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to create a two-column layout for my page using divs. Something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left_column">
        {jQuery Datatable here}
    </div>
    <div class="right_column">
    </div>
</div>
```

What happened to me is that when the page is rendered, somehow jQuery closes the "wrapper" div so it looks like this (I use Chrome's Inspect this element to view the code):

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left_column">
        {jQuery Datatable here}
    </div>
</div>  ---------------------------- Why?
<div class="right_column">
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Edit: It turned out that our page processor was the one responsible for this :(. Nothing wrong with jQuery.

Comment: Based on what you show, it shouldn't do this.  But I dunno what the DOM structure of the datatable is...

Comment: It is: "sDom": '<"top"pf<"clear">>t<"bottom"r<"buttons"><"clear">><"clear">'

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have the right_column outside the wrapper and have another wrapper that holds all:

```
<div class="parentWrapper">
    <div class="wrapper"> // float left
        <div class="left_column">
            {jQuery Datatable here}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right_column"> // float left or right

    </div>
</div>
```